# Changing Network Subnet Limited User Access

Tags: networking, wifi, subnet, pfsense

Our network was originally running a 192.168.3.1 /24 network with 192.168.3.1 being the gateway on a pfSense box. We decided to increase our IP range by changing the network to a 192.168.3.1 /23 network.

As a result, our network has expanded from an IP range of:

```
192.168.3.1 - 254
         To
192.168.2.1 - 192.168.3.254
```

All seemed to work until we noticed that users being assigned the 192.168.2.1 range are receiving limited connectivity while users being assigned the 192.168.3.254 addresses are connecting just fine. Even my personal IP receives the following information, but I have no internet connectivity:

```
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.2.7
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.254.0
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.3.1
```

To anyone's knowledge, would there be any other configuration changes required within pfSense besides the subnet to allow access? The 192.168.2.1 network is not in use. The reason for the pool of IP addresses below is because we have reserved IP's in place from 192.168.3.2-15 so we could not specify an absolute range.

Our DHCP Rules
[image]

Comment: Two things about your screenshot: `1.` The pool range you have shown in the editable fields is incorrect. It should be 192.168.2.1-192.168.3.254, but you show 192.168.2.1-192.168.2.254. `2.` Why do you have the additional pool defined? I don't know anything about pfSense so I don't know what the additional pool is meant for but you have it set to a range of addresses that is already encapsulated in your DHCP range. Perhaps that's part of the problem.

Comment: I had to specify that range because if not, pfsense states: "The specified range must not be within the range configured on a DHCP pool for this interface. The DHCP range cannot overlap any static DHCP mappings." This is due to existing reservations, so my intention is to use 192.168.2.1-254 and 192.168.3.15-254 since 192.168.3.1-15 are taken. I would think that this would work if you notice the statement "If you need additional pools of addresses inside of this subnet outside the above Range, they may be specified here."

Comment: dhcp settings look ok. check firewall rules

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that your default gateway (192.168.3.1) isn't aware that the 192.168.2.0/24 hosts are on the same subnet.  It probably thinks that the contiguous subnet is 192.168.3.2 - 192.168.4.254.

Expand your DHCP scope to encompass 192.168.4.0/24 and you should be OK.
Stop using 192.168.2.0/24.

Comment: Perhaps, but if this is true, that would be one silly router :)